# Time complexity of for loop with if/else

Tags: time-complexity, big-o

Would the following code be considered `O(1)` or `O(n)`? The for loop has constant complexity which runs 10 times but I'm not sure whether the if condition would be considered `O(n)` or `O(1)`.

```
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
if (arr [i] == 1001)
    {
        return i;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The complexity would be `O(1)`, because regardless of how much you increase the input the complexity of the algorithm remains constant. Namely, the operations performed inside that loop are considered to have constant time, hence `O(1)`.

```
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    if (arr [i] == 1001) 
    {
        return i;
    }
}
```

On the other hand if your loop was:

```
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    f(n)
}
```

and the function `f(n)` had a complexity of `O(n)` then the complexity of the entire code snippet would be `O(n)` since 10 * N can be labeled as `O(n)`.

For a more in depth explanation have a look at [What is a plain English explanation of “Big O” notation?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66110339/1366871)